# Is there any way to add this two array to get a new list in python

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, merge

I want to simulate a left outer join of these two arrays
array = ['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e']
array2 = ['a', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'b']
which the results will be as follows.
opt = ['aa', 'aa', ,'bb','c_', 'd_', 'e_']

Comment: You can try using [map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/) or [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) combined with [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip). I highly suggest checking them out in the python docs. Personally I prefer list comprehension (i.e. iterating through lists in a different syntax in order to build and return a new list) + zip simply for the sake of readability, but I think map will be easier to understand for a beginner.

Comment: Also I just looked over your question, do you want to combine the strings in each list with the matching string in the other? Or are you trying to do something else? Because if you are trying to combine strings then it should be `array = ['a','b','c','d','e']; array2 = ['a','a','f','g','b']; array3 = ['aa','ba','cf','dg','eb']`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is the result I'm trying to get   >>> array3 = ['aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'c_', 'd_', 'e_']   merging the two common elements together

Comment: how do you get this `['aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'c_', 'd_', 'e_'] ` from the merge ?   where do the values come from ?  where does the second `aa` come from or the `bb` and why is `c_` in the 4th position in the expected result array ?

Comment: @D.L here is the given question and expected solution                                                        I want to simulate a left outer join of these two arrays array = ['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e'] array2 = ['a', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'b'] which the results will be as follows. opt = ['aa', 'aa', ,'bb','c_', 'd_', 'e_']                                     firstly, we have to sort array2 to solve the problem. I got the solution using data frame, but I needed to return the solution as opt = ['aa', 'aa', ,'bb','c_', 'd_', 'e_']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do an outer left join this might work:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
array2 =  ['a', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'b']
array3 = []
for i in array:
 subarray = []
 for j in array2:
  if i == j: 
   subarray.append(i+j)
  else: 
   subarray.append(i+"_")
 if any([n[1] != "_" for n in subarray]):
  for n in subarray:
   if n[1] != "_":
    array3.append(n)
 else:
  array3.append(i + "_")
```

Comment: That's what I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 0):

The question was a bit ambiguous as the comments have pointed out.

But it appears from the question that you are trying to get all the combinations (and not just add the two lists)...

If this is the case then nested for loops (or list comprehension) are two basic methods:

```py
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] 
array2 =['a', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'b'] 

all = []
for i in array:
    for j in array2:
        all.append(i+j)


print(all)
```

returns this:

```
['aa', 'aa', 'af', 'ag', 'ab', 'ba', 'ba', 'bf', 'bg', 'bb', 'ca', 'ca', 'cf', 'cg', 'cb', 'da', 'da', 'df', 'dg', 'db', 'ea', 'ea', 'ef', 'eg', 'eb']
```

If you are combining the lists then this would work:

```py
array = ['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e'] 
array2 =['a', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'b'] 

length = len(array)

new = []
for i in range(length):
    # some rules here
    v = array[i] + array2[i]
    new.append(v)

new
```

which gives this:

```
['aa', 'ba', 'cf', 'dg', 'eb']
```

In both cases, you can add rules in the (nested) for loops.

Comment: I tried this method but wasn't the result I needed. I want to join the two common elements together which the results will be as this >>> array3 = ['aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'c_', 'd_', 'e_']

Comment: Easier method to reach this solution: `array3 = [n + array2[i] for i, n in enumerate(array)]`, though this doesn't seem to be what op wants and, more importantly, it's probably better to guide op towards the method they need rather than let them copy paste it, because concepts like this are extremely key in python.

Comment: @Samuel you need to clarify how you want to get that output from the input; it seems like there is literally no correlation between input and output and you expect an inbuilt function. Any clarification at all would help, but just repeatedly stating what you expect isn't helpful.

Comment: I want to simulate a left outer join of these two arrays 
array = ['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e']
array2 = ['a', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'b']
which the results will be as follows.
opt = ['aa', 'aa', ,'bb','c_', 'd_', 'e_']